# Update com variavel PHP

Tags: php, mysql, variáveis

Estou tomando uma surra com um update com variavel. Por favor alguem pode me ajudar?

```
$servidorBanco = "localhost";
$usuarioBanco = "root";
$senhaBanco = "";
$dadosBanco = "db";

$conexao = new mysqli($servidorBanco, $usuarioBanco, $senhaBanco, $dadosBanco);  

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$hora = date('H:i:s');

$idHost = 1;

$consulta2 = $conexao->escape_string("UPDATE host SET uptimeHost='".$hora."', avisoHost=0 WHERE idHost='".$idHost);
$resultado4 = $conexao->query($consulta2);
```

Não esta atualizando no banco de dados MySQL.

Comment: Faz o que o `iPramesPortas` sugeriu, mas antes verifique se a sua consulta SQL está correta. Faz um `echo` na SQL e teste-a no seu banco.

Comment: Ja resolvi o problema, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pronto resolvi a resolução é essa

```
$servidorBanco = "localhost";
$usuarioBanco = "root";
$senhaBanco = "";
$dadosBanco = "db";

$conexao = new mysqli($servidorBanco, $usuarioBanco, $senhaBanco, $dadosBanco);  

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$hora = date('H:i:s');

$idHost = 1;

$sql = "UPDATE host SET uptimeHost='$hora', avisoHost=0 WHERE idHost='$idHost'";
if($conexao->query($sql) === true){
    echo "Atualizado com sucesso";
}else{
    echo "Não atualizado";
}
```

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0):

```
$hora = date('H:i:s'); $idHost = 1;


$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","banco");  

$sql = "update host set uptimeHost='$hora',avisoHost='0' where idHost='$idHost'"; 

$query = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
```

Comment: esse conexão já tem. Vou atualizar a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Esqueceu de fechas as aspas

seu código:

```
$consulta2 = $conexao->escape_string("UPDATE host SET uptimeHost='".$hora."', avisoHost=0 WHERE idHost='".$idHost);
```

como deveria ser:

```
$consulta2 = $conexao->escape_string("UPDATE host SET uptimeHost='$hora',avisoHost='0' WHERE idHost='$idHost');
```

Comment: da erro de pagina